# C++ Operator Overload and Inheritance

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

So I have a generic Matrix class that I created which has the following operator overload:

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix() {}
    Matrix(int i, int j, int k) {}
    Matrix operator*(const Matrix &right)
    {
    }
};
```

I also have a Matrix2 class that inherits from my Matrix class.

```
class Matrix2 : public Matrix
{
};
```

When I try to multiply two Matrix2 objects together I get a compiler error stating:

'there is no operator found which takes a left hand operand of type Matrix2 (or there is no accessible conversion)'

Why is this and how can I properly implement operator overloads with inheritance?

**EDIT:**

As pointed out my problem was partially because of the "most vexing parse". Now my problem, I believe, strictly has to do with the operator overload and inheritance.

I can multiply two Matrix objects just fine, but I cannot multiply two Matrix2 objects together.

```
Matrix2 i;
Matrix2 m;
Matrix result = m * i;
```

The error message:

> `error C2678: binary '*' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Matrix2' (or there is no acceptable conversion).`

Comment: this is just a guess, but could you try adding a `public` modifier before your overload declaration

Comment: The operator overload is in the public section of my Matrix class.

Comment: in all cases, a complete minimal compilable example that enables others to experience the same errors that you do is useful.

Comment: So it is not an inheritance problem... Just tried multiplying two Matrix objects and the compiler still complains.

Comment: An addition to @Motti's answer, try changing the declaration to `Matrix Matrix::operator*(const Matrix &right){}` in order for this operator overload to work correctly.

Comment: @Steztric Changing the declaration created more errors. What exactly does that do?

Comment: @Chris please post the compilation error (I assume you're returning a value from `operator*` BTW)

Comment: @Chris I compiled the supplied code with [IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/n9M6h) and it seems to be just fine.  What is the implementation for `operator*`?  On which line is the error?

Comment: @Kaiged the error is on the line "Matrix result = m * i"

Comment: @Chris Interesting, though as PlasmaHH stated, we could use code that will exhibit the same errors.  I'm also getting a hunch that your implementation of `operator*` could be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are biting the Most Vexing Parse. It is a syntactic error leading to the declaration of functions rather than objects.

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean. However, I have 2 constructors: one which takes no arguments and one that takes several arguments. When I declare 2 objects (one using the parameter-less constructor and one using the constructor with several parameters) and try multiplying them together the compiler still complains.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with the overloaded operator, it's with the variables you defined, you're probably thinking that `m1` and `m2` are of type `Matrix` but what they actually are is functions returning `Matrix` (with no parameters). Try removing the parentheses in the declaration and see if things look better.

This is the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) that @DeadMG is refering to in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this article](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html) on operator overloading, it explains things very well.

As @silvesthu explains, it might be better to implement the multiplication operator as a static function taking 2 arguments and returning a new `Matrix` object. If you need to modify your class in some way such as using the `*=` operator, you can implement this in terms of the static function.

**Update**

Compiling the following code works for me;

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix() {}
    Matrix(int i, int j, int k) {}
    Matrix operator*(const Matrix &right)
    {
        return Matrix();
    }
};

class Matrix2 : public Matrix
{
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Matrix2 a, b;
    Matrix c = a * b;
    return 0;
}
```

Showing that two Matrix2 objects can indeed be multiplied together. I am not sure why you are getting any problems at all.